# Emacs abbrev-mode with auto-expansion(without space)

Tags: emacs

I want to use abbrev or something similar in term-mode instead of creating shell aliases. Reason being is it's nice to ssh somewhere and have the aliases available.

An annoyance is that I need to hit space for the abbrev to expand. For example if I have a short alias named `l5` that's used often, I don't want to hit space every time for a two char thing.

How can I have it expand without space? Perhaps on hitting enter?

Answer (score 1):

The function `expand-abbrev` will expand the abbrev at point. Expansion in abbrev mode is handled at a low level inside the internal functions of `self-insert-command` so you cannot just specify a new key.

You can however find a way to run `expand-abbrev` before sending the shell your input.

Whether you're using shell or term, it may be tricky. You can likely advise `comint-send-input` or `term-send-raw` respectively to deterministically run `expand-abbrev` before sending the text off.

Here is an example to support <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd> abbrev expansion in `term`.

```lisp
(defadvice term-send-raw (before maybe-expand-in-term activate)
  (when (called-interactively-p)
    (let ((keys (this-command-keys)))
      ;; if key was enter or space, expand abbrev at point
      (when (or (equal keys (string 13))
               (equal keys " "))
        (expand-abbrev)))))
```